# Empty string in python

Tags: python

newbie here in Python so i have a question for my code:

```
def unosenje_knjiga():
ime = str(input("Ime knjige:"))
autor = str(input("Autor knjige:"))
isbn = str(input("ISBN knjige:"))
zanr = str(input("Zanr knjige:"))
izdavac = str(input("Izdavac knjige:"))
godina = str(input("Godina stampe:"))
print ("Uspesno ste ubacili novu knjigu u sistem")
second_meni()
```

The problem here is when i run the program i can easily click enter and the next string will follow. How do i make it so that i need write something in order for the next string to come up. Thanks

Comment: Reproduce your indentation accurately when you're posting Python code. Otherwise you're introducing new problems into the code that you are asking people to look at.

Comment: `if` statements and `while` loops will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use `raw_input` for example :

```
    response = ""
    while (response != "Valid Answer"):
        response = raw_input("ISBN knjige:\n");

    print "Question answered correcty show next question"
```

Comment: The problem OP is having, is that hitting enter will jump to the next question, which your answer doesn't solve.

Comment: @MooingRawr Thanks, the way i see it this new updated code should work, could be put inside of a function for repeated usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the len() function to determine the length of a string.
Code:

```
ime = str(input("Ime knjige:"))
while len(ime) <= 0:
    ime = str(input("Ime knjige:"))
print("Done")
```

Instead of printing "Done" you can do the next input sequence.

Answer your question?

Comment: Or `while not ime:`, which is more idiomatic Python.

Comment: Thanks mate. This is what i was looking for